# threadPool.SetMaxThreads returning false

Tags: c#

My understanding of SetMaxThreads() in C# was that it can not be set to less than the number of processors.

But in my code I am unable to set the number to less than 8, I have no idea why this is.

If I set it to lower it returns false!

(Running an Intel Core 2)

Answer (score 3):

I think I have solved this problem now (kinda!), if SetMinThreads() is first set to the minimum number, so in my case 2, then we are able to set the max number of threads to a value less than 8.

I am aware that this then ties of resources with idle threads, but for my purposes it is a suitable work around.

Comment: Yeah, you can't set the max lower than the min.